# Turn ON radio using wlan api

Tags: c#, windows, interop, wlanapi

I have requirement to turn off wireless radio using wlanapi in `C#`.
Iam able to turn off the radio but not able to turn on.
Here is my code:

```
WLAN_PHY_RADIO_STATE wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state = new WLAN_PHY_RADIO_STATE();
wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state.dwPhyIndex = 0; // TODO : can change ???
wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state.dot11HardwareRadioState = DOT11_RADIO_STATE.dot11_radio_state_on;// ignored in fact, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706791(v=vs.85).aspx 
wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state.dot11SoftwareRadioState = DOT11_RADIO_STATE.dot11_radio_state_on;

radioStatePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state, radioStatePtr, false);

if (WlanEnumInterfaces(handle, IntPtr.Zero,
              out ppInterfaceList) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{

    interfaceList = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(ppInterfaceList);



    for (int i = 0; i < interfaceList.dwNumberofItems; i++)
    {
        Guid pInterfaceGuid = ((WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO)interfaceList.InterfaceInfo[0]).InterfaceGuid;

        if (WlanSetInterface(handle, ref pInterfaceGuid, WLAN_INTF_OPCODE.wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state, dataSize, ref ptr, IntPtr.Zero) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            MessageBox.Show("yes");
        else MessageBox.Show("Some Issue");

    }
}
```

Definition :

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint WlanSetInterface(IntPtr hClientHandle, ref Guid      pInterfaceGuid, WLAN_INTF_OPCODE OpCode, uint dwDataSize, ref  IntPtr pData, IntPtr pReserved);
```

Everything going smooth I mean wlansetinterface function returning `ERROR_SUCCESS` but radio is not swithching on in my PC.please help where i missed ?

I fallowed [How can I turn ON radio of a Wifi adapter that is actually OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985628/how-can-i-turn-on-radio-of-a-wifi-adapter-that-is-actually-off)

Comment: What OS is running on your device? The code and link are about Windows 7 and not Compact Framework. For CF use OpenNetCF (ie https://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/e7233249-6758-6bec-b816-c2c0ad7f46b5.htm)

Comment: Hey @josef ... Thanks for your reply. I'm looking for solution in windows7 itself in C#.

Comment: So why doesn't your code match the link you provided that does work?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I Used the same code only ... Error prints to debug nothing much diference